# ngModel doesn't display the value of an object in mat-select

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I have a company class, it has an headquarter's address field. The address is an interface, it has an another object, country, which is an another interface.
In my database I store all the countries. I have a view for editing a selected company, there I can set or change the headquarter's address and I created a mat-select for the countries:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="company.headquarter.country">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of companyService.countries" [value]="country">
        {{country.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

This code save the selected country to the headquarter's country field, but if I want to edit the same company the mat-select doesn't display the actual value. how can I solve this problem?

**Edited:**

If I change the ngModel to company.headquarter.country.id and the [value] to country.id, then it works fine, but to store the country's code or name I have to write a method, which will find the country by the id in the companyService.countries array and set this country to the company.headquarter.country's field. So it is not a good solution.

Comment: Is it ChangeDetection issue ? Your main component is in OnPush detection strategy ? if yes, please check https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this? I've also gone the route to have a method figure out what the id v value should be once the selection is completed since binding the value to the Id and displaying the value does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This code save the selected country to the headquarter's country
>   field, but if I want to edit the same company the mat-select doesn't
>   display the actual value. how can I solve this problem?

The problem is when you mat-select compares two object, their references can be different. Use `compare function` to compare your object by some mark like `id`.

> To customize the default option comparison algorithm, 
>   supports `compareWith` input. `compareWith` takes a function which has two
>   arguments: option1 and option2. If `compareWith` is given, Angular
>   selects option by the return value of the function.

**Template:**

```
 <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select [(value)]="contract.company"
                          panelClass="example-panel-dark-blue"
                          [compareWith]="helper.compareById">

                <mat-option *ngFor="let cust of customers"
                            [value]="cust"> {{cust.title}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**Code:**

```
 compareById(f1: Common.Item, f2: Common.Item): boolean {
     return f1 && f2 && f1.id === f2.id;
 }
```

[Official Doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection)

Comment: Cool! Happy to help 

Answer (score 1):

Change `[(ngModel)]` to `[(value)]`.

```
<mat-select [(value)]="company.headquarter.country"> 
  <mat-option *ngFor="let country of companyService.countries" [value]="country"> {{country.name}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Same problem. With this solution saving the country to the company.headquarter.country is working, but when I want to edit, the mat-select doesn't display the current value.

Comment: Is your mat-select inside mat-form-field?

Comment: https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts

Comment: Yes, it is inside a mat-form-field. The link doesn't work!

Comment: It also might be an object identity problem. Remember that in js { hello: 'world' } !== { hello:  'world } so I would advise binding the select to a scalar value.